# SecurityError: Error #2000 With AS3 Loader in CS5 But not CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, security, loader

I have a external swf loader that works fine in CS6. However, when people use it in CS5.5 I get a dreaded security error. How could I fix this?

```
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
loaderContext.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
if (Security.sandboxType != "localTrusted") {
    loaderContext.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;// Sets the security 
}
var sdk_url:String = "http://example.com/external.swf?="+new Date().getTime();
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(sdk_url);
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete, false, 0, true);
loader.load(urlRequest, loaderContext);
```

Comment: CS6? CS5.5? Are you confusing these with Flash versions?

Comment: It works fine in cs6. I get the error in cs5.5. Also people are reporting problems with cs4. I think it might be because the server header is responding with content-type as json instead of flash. I'm not sure though.

Comment: I don't understand. CS4, CS5, CS6 those are Flash IDE software. Are you saying those people are running the code with those software?

Comment: Yes, other developers are having the issue with older flash IDEs. Although, the web flash player and CS6 IDE work without errors.

Comment: They just need to make sure to set the as3 version and the security sandbox correctly.